Without type assertions, can I give an interface's function a private parameter?
Without type assertions, can I give an interface's function a private parameter? Here's what I mean by "private":

This parameter can be passed within the current module.
External to the current module, that parameter cannot be used.

This code demonstrates what I'd like to be able to do:
export interface PublicInterface {
  publicFunction1: (foo: string) => string;
  publicFunction2: () => string;
}

export const implementation: PublicInterface = {
  publicFunction1: function (foo: string | number): string {
    return "abc";
  },
  publicFunction2: function (): string {
    return implementation.publicFunction1(123); // I'd like this to compile without a type assertion
  },
};

// another-file.ts
implementation.publicFunction1("xyz");
implementation.publicFunction1(123); // I'd like this to continue to error


I tried to accomplish this with function overloads instead of an interface, but I got an error when I did not export every overload: "Overload signatures must all be exported or non-exported." This leads me to believe this isn't possible without a type assertion, but I thought I would ask anyway. If there is a way to do this I'd like to learn it.

Given that the actual type of implementation is assignable to PublicInterface, can't you just have an internal unannotated thing and export implementation as the annotated version, as shown in this playground link (and note that I'm using namespace here but it should also be similar for modules)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I would accept that if it worked for modules, mainly because I've been unable to find documentation on namespace that I understand.

? I'm saying it almost certainly does work for modules; how could I demonstrate that to you? Could you check it? Or do I need to come up with a web IDE project with multiple files?

Okay, here is a codesandbox link demonstrating that it does indeed work for modules. So, should I write an answer, or do you still need to check something more?

Why not define a private implementation using satisfies and then export it with the desired annotation for public use like this? If that meets your needs, I can write it as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I think I misunderstood the parenthetical in your first comment. Yeah that would work for me

@jsejcksn that fits my needs, thanks

@jsejcksn our suggestions are very similar. Do you want to write up the answer here or let me do it?

@jcalz I just looked at your comment and I agree. However, I don’t think namespaces are needed for the solution, so if you’re planning to write an answer that doesn’t use that feature, go ahead and I’ll abstain.

I was just using namespaces to demonstrate modules in a TS Playground link, not as an important feature of the answer. My answer won't mention namespaces at all.

If export const x: X = ⋯ works, you can split that assignment into two pieces:

define the internal thing with all the functionality you need internally, like const internalX = ⋯; and
assign the internal thing to the exported thing, whose type is annotated with the public-facing annotation, like export const x: X = internalX;

Like this:
export interface PublicInterface {
  publicFunction1: (foo: string) => string;
  publicFunction2: () => string;
}

// not exported, narrower type
const internalImplementation = {
  publicFunction1: function (foo: string | number): string {
    return "abc";
  },
  publicFunction2: function (): string {
    return internalImplementation.publicFunction1(123); // okay
  },
};

// exported, wider type
export const implementation: PublicInterface = internalImplementation;

So the implementation of publicFunction2 works because it's using internalImplementation.  And when you import, you'll only have access to the external view:
import { implementation } from "./myModule";
implementation.publicFunction1("xyz"); // okay
implementation.publicFunction1(123); // error, number not assignable to string

Code sandbox link to code

I'd also consider adding satisfies PublicInterface to const internalImplementation: While a bit redundant with the assignment that follows, it may improve code completion while writing the implementation, and offer more localized compiler messages in the event of a type mismatch between PublicInterface and internalImplementation.
